# VHDL: Indexing in component port map

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

```
    comp_A1: comp_A port map    (   CLK     =>  CLK,
                                    RESET_N =>  RESET_N,
                                    DATA_IN =>  DATA(to_integer(unsigned(count))),
                                    VLD_IN  =>  VLD_IN,
                                    DATA_OUT=>  DATA_OUT,
                                    VLD_OUT =>  VLD_OUT,
                                    BUSY_OUT=>  BUSY_OUT
                                );
```

In the above snippet I am trying to pass 'DATA' **serially** to the 'DATA_IN' pin of component comp_A1 within a testbench. **'DATA' and 'count' are both std_logic_vectors**. All other signals are std_logic. 'DATA' is a constant vector of size 64 bits and 'count' is a vector being incremented at every rising edge(CLK).

During compilation Model Sim shows me the following errors only,

1. (vcom-1450) Actual (indexed name) for formal "DATA_IN" is not a static signal name.
2. VHDL Compiler exiting.

Is the error to do with 'count' being dynamic? What would be a workaround to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move the multiplexer created with the line `DATA(to_integer(unsigned(count)))` to a separate statement using an intermediate signal, for example:

```
selected_data <= DATA(to_integer(unsigned(count)));
```

...

```
DATA_IN => selected_data
```

Comment: Works! Another question is-- is there now way to pass a dynamically indexed value in a port map in VHDL? I am pretty sure this can be done in Verilog.

Comment: Is your suggestion the only method? Because it has the overhead of declaring an extra signal.

Comment: I don't understand your 'another question'. Perhaps you could edit your original question with an extra section for this new part.

Comment: What overhead? It's just good design to use a signal to make the functionality explicit, rather than obfuscate the meaning by burying it in the port map.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I think your original code would work were you using VHDL 2008, because in VHDL 2008 expressions are allowed in port maps (whereas in VHDL 2002, the actual - RHS - of a port map needs to be a name).

Comment: @BrianDrummond I disagree that it's bad design choice to assign pieces of signals on the port map. When you have a set of signals/ports that your working group is familiar with, it can make the code more readable if you reduce the amount of overhead. You need to balance things, I personally hate going round and round the whole code just to follow a signal name changes. Scattering a signal's functionality around the code like this can be just as bad.

Comment: @suoto : the case here isn't a slice extraction or a type conversion but dynamic code (a different bit of `DATA` every time `count` changes) : now that's obscure! I completely agree with you that extracting (static!) slices or type converting from familiar names improves readability.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Ops, my bad. You are right, that's not something I would feel comfortable doing.

Comment: @suoto : just goes to show how easy it is to confuse people with obscure code :-)